# How to add custom CSS classes to Shiny app elements

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a shiny app consisting of multiple rows (fluidRow) and columns.

Example code

```
library( shiny )
library( ggplot2 )

ui <- navbarPage(
  'NaVarTitle',
  tabPanel(
    'TAB1',
    fluidRow( column( 4, plotOutput("Plot1") ),
              column( 4, plotOutput("Plot2") ),
              column( 4, plotOutput("Plot3") ),
            )
  ),
  tabPanel(
    'TAB2',
    fluidRow( column( 12, plotOutput("Plot4") ) )
  ),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=1:10) )
  })
  output$Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=10:1) )
  })
  output$Plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=rep(1,10), y=10:1) )
  })
  output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=10:1) )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Example app (divs are shown using Pesticide chrome extension)

[image]

This seems very similar to Bootstrap and uses very similar classes to build the UI.

[image]

I know we can use customm CSS inline or with an external CSS file [shiny CSS](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html). I also found documentation regarding [shiny themes](https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/).

However, I would like to customise the UI by adding my own CSS classes to the rows and columns so I can build a more personalized design. Is there any way of adding a class to the elements that shiny creates?

I am thinking something like the following, but cannot find a way of doing it

```
  ...
  tabPanel(
            'TAB1',
            class = 'myRowClass',
            fluidRow( column( 4, plotOutput("Plot1"), class= 'myColClass' ),
                      column( 4, plotOutput("Plot2"), class= 'myColClass' ),
                      column( 4, plotOutput("Plot3"), class= 'myColClass' ),
                    )
          ),
  ...
```

---

Edit to add solution:
Turns out it is easy to add custom classes, I leave here the example just in case is useful to someone with the same doubt

```
library( shiny )
library( ggplot2 )
library( dplyr )

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
    # Note the wrapping of the string in HTML()
    tags$style(HTML("
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Yusei+Magic&display=swap');
        .my_col_class {
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
        }
        .myrowclass {
          background-color: pink;
        }
        .my_col_class2 {
          background-color: green;
        }"))
  ),
    navbarPage(
    'NaVarTitle',
    tabPanel(
      'TAB1',
      fluidRow( column( 4, plotOutput("Plot1") ) %>% tagAppendAttributes( class = 'my_col_class2' ) ,
                column( 4, plotOutput("Plot2"), class="my_col_class" ),
                column( 4, plotOutput("Plot3") ),
                class = 'myrowclass'
              )
    ),
    tabPanel(
      'TAB2',
      fluidRow( column( 12, plotOutput("Plot4") ) )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=1:10) )
  })
  output$Plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=10:1) )
  })
  output$Plot3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=rep(1,10), y=10:1) )
  })
  output$Plot4 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() + geom_point( aes(x=1:10, y=10:1) )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) will be of help.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, @Limey , you are pointing to the first link of my post. It explains how to add custom CSS inline or as an external file but not how to add custom CSS classes to shiny elements. Thanks again

Comment: Just add you custom CSS classes to your app, either by adding them to an external CSS file or to the app itself using `tags$head`.  Or are you asking for a tutorial on how to write CSS?

Comment: Thanks Limey, turns out I did something wrong in my tests because my code actually works. @lantang suggestion also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tagAppendAttributes()`

```
  tabPanel(
    'TAB1',
    fluidRow( column( 4, plotOutput("Plot1")) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class="my_col_class"),
              column( 4, plotOutput("Plot2")) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class="my_col_class"),
              column( 4, plotOutput("Plot3")) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class="my_col_class"),
    ) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class="my_row_class") 
  )
```